# Image tag not updating inside the UpdatePannel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I hope you are coding well,
I am working on a Image Upload module , which is in a Modal Popup and hence is wrapped inside an Update Panel,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdateModelPopup" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkUploadImage" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlModel" CssClass="ModalWindow">
                    <!-- Style="display: none;" -->
                    <table border="0" class="modalTable" cellspacing="5">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Keywords 2<strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font></strong> &nbsp;<i>(Seperated by , )</i>
                                <br />
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtKeywordsTwo"></asp:TextBox><br />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Dimensions <strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font></strong>
                                <br />
                                &nbsp;Width :&nbsp;
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDimWidth" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                                &nbsp;Height :
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDimHeight" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <hr />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Browse .psd file<br />
                                    <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="pdfFile" Width="200px" OnUploadedComplete="pdfFile_UploadedComplete"
                                        CompleteBackColor="" ErrorBackColor="" OnClientUploadComplete="Success" />
                                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgThumbNail" /><br />
                                    <font color="#FF0000">or</font><br />
                                    Refrence URL<br />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Browse file <i>(.jpeg, .gif or .png)</i><strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font></strong><br />
                                    <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="AsyncFileUpload1" Width="200px" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now as per the business requirement, I need to show a thumbnail of the Image that user uploads, and for .psd file I have a standard icon which I display's at the run time, in the code behind I am validating the file extension to be the .psd file and it is then display the psd icon, I am trying to set the ImageURL for

```
protected void pdfFile_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(e.FileName).ToString().ToLower() != ".psd")
        {
            string alertMsg = @"alert('Please provide .PSD type file');"; 
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Test", alertMsg, true);
            //pdfFile
        }
        else
        {
            imgThumbNail.ImageUrl ="~/images/psdIcon.jpg";
        }
    }
```

The problem is that Panel doesnt gets update at the run time, even the page source shows src="". I am suspecting that its a Update Panel issue.

Kindly point me into the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`FileUpload` can not be done `Asynchronously`. In order to do that `PostBackTrigger` Trigger will be required to upload.

Comment: FileUpload is working fine, infact the first block of code :

if (Path.GetExtension(e.FileName).ToString().ToLower() != ".pdf")
        {
            string alertMsg = @"alert('Please provide .PDF type file');"; 
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Test", alertMsg, true);
            //pdfFile
        }

Is able to validate and display JavaScript message.

Comment: Add this line `UpdatePanelID.Update();` before the line `imgThumbNail.ImageUrl ="~/images/psdIcon.jpg";`

Comment: This link is also useful http://forums.asp.net/t/1779241.aspx/1?Image+is+not+refreshed+in+updatePanel+Update

Comment: I really appreciate your contribution on this, I none of above worked but I have realized that its not a problem with the Image control, I am able to set the ImageURL on other events/postback, but the problem is only file calling it under : protected void pdfFile_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    }, So I think this function doesn't have access to the form controls collection class, don't know, doesn't have much esperiance with it actually.

Comment: as you said first block is working. try it with `ViewState`. Store it in `ViewState` and access it in this handler.

Comment: Sure Pankaj I'll give it a try, I think using AsynFileUPload is not a good idea, I'll try looking for some other alternates, (btw: don't know who and why have reduced my reputation by 2 number :-P )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9673/discussion-between-vishal-and-pankaj-garg)