# UpdatePanel doesn't update

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Am using an AJAX Async File Upload to add a user image.  I want the image to be updated once the Async upload is done.  I'm using upImage.Update() in the code behind to do this, but it doesn't seem to do the update.

All the code runs through without error and there are no errors in the JS console.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

The aspx file:

```
<h2>That's You 
        <ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="afuUserImage" runat="server" 
            OnUploadedComplete="uploadComplete"  
            UploadedFileError="uploadError"             
            Width="200px"  
            UploadingBackColor="#b9b9b9" 
            CompleteBackColor="#00FF00"
            ErrorBackColor="#FF0000"
            ThrobberID="theLoader" 
            ClientIDMode="AutoID"  
            CssClass="" />
    </h2>
    <div id="userSettingsImage" runat="server" class="userSettingsImage"> 
        <asp:updatepanel ID="upImage" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgUser" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/graphics/blankuser.jpg" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>       
    </div>
```

And the code behind....

```
    protected void uploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // change photo in space and upload to user photo
            if (afuUserImage.HasFile)
            {

                string strPath = Server.MapPath("~/users/" + this.Context.User.Identity.Name + "/userimages/" + this.Context.User.Identity.Name + ".jpg");
                if (File.Exists(strPath))
                {
                    File.Delete(strPath);
                }
                afuUserImage.SaveAs(strPath);
                imgUser.ImageUrl = imgUser.ImageUrl + "?new" + String.Format("{0:ddMMyyyy}", DateTime.Now);
                upImage.Update();
                Lifeklips_Global.eComms.showMessage("All done!");
            }
            else
            {
                Lifeklips_Global.eComms.showMessage("Oops! This is embarrassing. Your update didn't work, but we're looking into it.  Give it another go.");                    
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Lifeklips_Global.errorProcess.logError("Error uploading file: " + ex.Message, "Lifeklips.UserControls.singlephotouploader:uploadComplete");
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image tag not updating inside the UpdatePannel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995399/image-tag-not-updating-inside-the-updatepannel)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got the wrong ImageUrl

```
imgUser.ImageUrl = imgUser.ImageUrl + "?new" + String.Format("{0:ddMMyyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

Should be

```
imgUser.ImageUrl = "~/users/" + this.Context.User.Identity.Name + "/userimages/" + this.Context.User.Identity.Name + ".jpg?new" + String.Format("{0:ddMMyyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: That's what it will be using the imgUser.ImageURL